# How to filter the dates based on range for datetime in django

Tags: python, django

```
views.py

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        from_date = request.POST.get("from_date")
        f_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
        print(f_date)
        to_date = request.POST.get("to_date")
        t_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        print(t_date)
        global get_records_by_date
        get_records_by_date = Scrapper.objects.all().filter(Q(start_time__range=f_date),Q(end_time__range=t_date))
        print(get_records_by_date)
```

I need to get the dates from the range start time and end time based on datetime field. When I run the script its showing TypeError at / 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable. Is there any solution for particular issue

[image: Table structure]

Comment: `__range` requires *two* values. You are looking for `__gt` and `__lt` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`__range`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) expects a 2-tuple with the from and to datetime, so:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from_date = request.POST.get('from_date')
        f_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        to_date = request.POST.get('to_date')
        t_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        get_records_by_date = Scrapper.objects.filter(
            some_date_field__range=(f_date, t_date)
        )
        # …
```

I would however advise to work with a form to process and clean the input, and *not* use a global variable: global state, especially in a webserver is a very bad idea.

Comment: Is it doesnt require to check end_time__range

Comment: @Ajay No it expects one tuple in which start_date and end_date is mentioned. It works in a way `some_date_field__range=(start_date end_date)`

Comment: @Ajay Sorry I forgot `,` in between it works as `some_date_field__range=(start_date, end_date)`

Answer (score 1):

You can put dates in the filter to find our range in between the dates.

```
import datetime

from_date=datetime.datetime.today().date()-datetime.timedelta(days=29)
to_date=datetime.datetime.today().date()
Somemodel.objects.filter(date_created__gte=from_date, date_created__lte=to_date)
```